# Access levels configuration tab not visible in TFS 2015

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

We're trying to configure Access Levels for an on-premise TFS 2015 server as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/security/change-access-levels#tfs-2015-tfs-2013).

However the "Access levels" tab in Control Panel is not visible to our TFS Administrator. He has administration right for both the Team Collection and Team Project. We're not running TFS Express, so this should be available to us.

This leaves us wondering, what are the requirements to be able to configure Access levels in TFS 2015? Is there something we are missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see the **Access levels** tab, you need to add the user to **Team Foundation Administrators group**

> If you don't see the Access levels tab, you aren't a TFS administrator
>   and don't have permission. Here's [how to get permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/add-administrator-tfs) (Add
>   administrators to TFS).

You can quickly grant these permissions to administrators by adding them to the Team Foundation Administrators group from **TFS administration console** in Team Foundation Server (TFS).

Follow the steps mentioned in this link : [Add administrators to TFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/add-administrator-tfs):

1. On the application-tier server, add the user to the **local
   Administrators group**.
2. In the TFS administration console and add the user to the set of
   users who can run the administration console.

   - Make sure you have selected the `Add user to Team Foundation Administrators group` item.

[image]