# Unable to get Access level tab in TFS

Tags: tfs

I am using TFS 2013, Update 5.

I am unable to see the 'Access Levels' tab in the admin section.

Verified also that the account has Console Permissions.

Added the account in `[TEAM FOUNDATION]\Team Foundation Administrators` group in TFS Admin Console.

While sending request from my site. I am getting

```
Request URL: `http://<account_name>:8080/tfs/_admin/_licenses`<br>
Request Method:  GET<br> Status Code: 404 Not Found<br> X-TFS-ServiceError:
Page+not+found.
```

The tab just simply isn't there.

And also I am unable to see the TEST tab in the projects.

Tried the solution: [Access levels configuration tab not visible in TFS 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48931538/access-levels-configuration-tab-not-visible-in-tfs-2015)

I have cleared the TFS_cache and restarted the server. Even after that, I am unable to view the tab though I have added myself to Team Foundation Administrators Group. Because of this access I am unable to view the Test tab in the project collection home page, Access tab in control section and Adding / Modifing charts under work item.

Kindly help me to fix the issue.

Comment: Could you try https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/organizations/security/change-access-levels?view=tfs-2013

Comment: Do other users who added in the `Team Foundation Administrators group` have the same issue? Have you tried this on other client machines?

Comment: No one is able to access TEST Tab. Have tried in different machines as well. Even the admin doesn't have access to test tab and Access level tab. These 2 tabs are missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even after multiple ways in the admin level if you are unable to see tab, Navigate to TFS console-->Application Tier-->Administration Security. Under users and Groups section select [Team Foundation]\Team Foundation Valid Users and set the permission of **Edit Instance-level information** to **Allow**. This way it has solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just check the [access level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/organizations/security/change-access-levels?view=tfs-2013) or your account, make sure you are not in the **Stakeholder** level. Just change the access level to **Basic** or **Advanced** Level if the user was in Stakeholder level.

> If you change the default access level to Stakeholder, all users not
>   explicitly added to the Basic or Advanced level will be limited to the
>   features provided through Stakeholder access.

Then try the solution mentioned in this thread: [Access levels configuration tab not visible in TFS 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48931538/access-levels-configuration-tab-not-visible-in-tfs-2015)

Besides, based on the error message "`Status Code: 404 Not Found`", generally it should an client-side issue. SO, just try below things to narrow down the issue:

- Using IP instead of the server name in URL, e.g :
  `http://192.168.1.10:8080/tfs/_admin/_licenses`
- Try with other client machines or browsers
- Cleaning the caches on your current client machine

Check if that works for you.

> **Cause of HTTP 404 Errors**:
>
> Technically, an Error 404 is a client-side error, implying that the
>   error is your mistake, either because you typed the URL incorrectly or
>   the page has been moved or removed from the website and you should
>   have known.
>
> Another possibility is if a website has moved a page or resource but
>   did so without redirecting the old URL to the new one. When that
>   happens, you'll receive a 404 error instead of being automatically
>   routed to the new page.

If that still not work, then try to repair the TFS server, then try it again.

Comment: If I am searching with ip http://192.168.1.10:8080/tfs/_admin/_licenses page is redirecting to error page. If the same server is searched without having _licenses the page will be displayed as shown in the above screenshot. Is there is any configuration mismatch from IIIS, DB or TFS?

Comment: @PriyaSinghka Seems your current user account is in Stakeholder access level... Whatever just try to clean caches, restart TFS server, then check it again. You can also reference this similar thread for troubleshooting : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/321ff964-34c3-41f3-b4ef-84a6315a1c72/cant-see-access-levels-tab-in-tfs-2013-web-access-administrative-area

Comment: @PriyaSinghka Have you resolved the issue? any update?

Comment: Nope. I am still unable to find the tab.

Comment: @PriyaSinghka If the TFS components were not corrupted, then it should be the permission issue.  You need to double check if you have really added the user to `Team Foundation Administrators group`.

Comment: I have cleared the TFS_cache and restarted the server. Even after that, I am unable to view the tab though I have added myself to Team Foundation Administrators Group. Because of this access I am unable to view the Test tab in the project collection home page, Access tab in control section and Adding / Modifing charts under work item.