# How do I make it possible for a user to add a feature in the Backlog view

Tags: tfs-2015

I've got a user whose added an epic to a backlog item in TFS's Backlog view. Now she'd like to add a feature beneath that epic, but she claims, she cannot. The green plus sign never shows up. I've checked her permissions and she's a member of the Project Administrators. I would have thought that would be sufficient; she says she still cannot get a green arrow. The only other thing I can think of is access levels. I've only been able to get to access levels once, several months back. I'm sorry, but I don't remember how I got there, so if this issue is related to access levels, how do I get to those, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I make it possible for a user to add a feature in the Backlog view

It should be more related to the access levels.

To go the access levels, you should enter the root directory of the TFS server in your browser, like:

```
http://xxxx2015:8080/tfs/
```

Then edit the **Manager server** button:

[image]

[image]

Then change the access levels of that user to **Basic**.

If you still can not see the access levels tab, check if you are in the **Team Foundation Administrators group**:

Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48931538/access-levels-configuration-tab-not-visible-in-tfs-2015?rq=1) for some details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, Leo. I see now what I was doing wrong. I went into the TFS Team Project, to try and find the access level. I thought access levels were defined at that point. I now see they're defined at the TFS server level.